# Unknow Hostname Exception. loopj library

Tags: java, android, put, loopj

Well i am using the loopj library for uploading mulitple form data, but the problem is it is giving me java.io.UnknownHost Exception, although i tried the same query with postman and it submitted the data successfully. 
please kindly help me go through the problem, it is drowning me.

```
  public void submit() {
            progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait,  Inserting Data on Server");
            progressDialog.show();

            File myFile = new File(selectedImageUri.getPath().toString());
            RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
            try {
                params.put("image", myFile);
                params.put("id", "" +104);
                params.put("latitude", "33333");
                params.put("longitude", "55555");
                params.put("task_status", "3");
                params.put("remarks", "dilievered");

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            }
            AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
            client.setTimeout(60000);
            client.put(ProcessTask.this,WebServicesURLS.UPDATE_TASK, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(ProcessTask.this, "Succesfuly updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(ProcessTask.this, "Failed"+statusCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
```

[logcat image.....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcEfj.png)

Comment: Add the logcat as text. And what you have in the image is **not** logcat

Comment: my mistake its the debug capture. logcat doesn't capture anything as its an exception

Comment: logcat *contains* the exception stacktraces...

Answer (score 0):

You have malformed URL. Please check if under WebServicesURLS.UPDATE_TASK reference you have correct url.

Comment: But have you tried this url in your browser for example? It doesn't even look like something that might work

Comment: 175.107.63.52/APIsPHC/api/tasklists/UpdateTaskList
 kindly check it

Comment: So this is a valid url. But the one you are using in your app is 175-107-63-52.reverse.ntc.net.pk, and as you see they are different. Please check what exactly do you have under WebServicesURLS.UPDATE_TASK reference